# Get Thin server to restart while picking up changes in newly deployed directory

Tags: capistrano, thin

After deploying using capistrano where I have a deploy task that is restarting the thin server, the changes that were just deployed are not getting picked up by the thin server.

Even if I manually run the thin restart command from the new deploy directory:

```
bundle exec thin restart -S /tmp/app.sock -e production -d
```

I can see the pid of the process change but it seems to keep serving up files from the old deploy directory. If I stop the thin server and start it again it works, but I want zero-downtime deploy to work.

As a follow-up it seems to just be restarting using the same code base that the last deploy used. I tried using "--chdir" to force it to use the new deploy directory, but it had no effect.